# Value of dyanamic select in jqGrid not being submitted

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm trying to create a grid with a column of type select, having dynamic options. The options are populated after the Edit Form is displayed.

My idea was to use the `dataInit` event as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291290/jqgrid-dynamic-select-option) answer.

The model for the column is:

```
 {name: 'bad', index: 'bad', editable: true, edittype: 'select',
  editoptions: {
    dataInit: function(elem) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(elem).empty()
          .append("<option value='1'>Option 1</option>")
          .append("<option value='2'>Option 2</option>");

      }, 50);
    }
  }
```

The options are correctly populated in the form, but when submitting, the value of the select field is not sent to the controller. I have used the `beforeSubmit` event to display the `data` object being sent:

```
beforeSubmit: function(data, id) {
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
   // Alerts:     {"":"1","list_id":"_empty"}
   // Notice that "" should be "bad"
}
```

Test it yourself: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6zaHp/137/

Comment: **Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in some version <=4.7)?** Where you set `editable: true` option? I don't see where you set some option from `address` `<select>` as `"selected"`.

Comment: @Oleg Both fields are editable, hidden, and edithidden, I added the missing attributes. I am using Guriddo v5.0. I do not set `"selected"` dynamically, I just populate the `<select>` and the user selects the address manually

Comment: Sorry, I develop free jqGrid and can't help you with specific Guriddo problems. You can post the support request to [Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=4). Alternatively you can try to verify whether the same problem exist in free jqGrid too. You need just change URLs to `ui.jqgrid.css`, `grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` like its described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If the same problem exist in free jqGrid then I could try to help you. If not then it should be probably a bug in Guriddo JS.

Comment: @Oleg The problem persists in free jqGrid. I have managed to narrow the cause of the problem and updated my question. I managed to get it working by providing a default value in `editoptions`. PS: Thank you for your work at jqGrid & SO activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `value: {}` for the select, which will be build dynamically.

```
{name: 'bad', editable: true, edittype: 'select',
  editoptions: {
    value: {},   // <-- Added this line
    dataInit: function(elem) {
      setTimeout(function() {
         $(elem).empty()
                .append("<option value='1'>Option 1</option>")
                .append("<option value='2'>Option 2</option>");
      }, 50);
   }
}
```

Without the setting jqGrid don't set some required attributes like the `name` attribute on the `<select>`. The `name` attribute will be used to build the property name of the resulting JSON data sent to the server.

See updated the corresponding demo here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6zaHp/139/